# No matching function for call, when returning an object

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++

`A` is a class defined by myself in `a.h`. Constructor `A(const char* str)` is defined in `a.cpp` as:

```
A::A(const char *str){
    ...
}
```

In file1.cpp, I want to return an A object: `return A("");`

When I compile `file1.cpp` with `g++` under Linux, I got following message:

> error: no matching function for call to 'A::A(A)',
>   candidates are: A::A(const char*)

Obviously an empty string `""` doesn't belong to class `A`. Can anyone tell me what is going wrong?

Comment: If I cook a sample program using the information you gave: [it works.](http://ideone.com/7cp1Cg) If you want to get help, give _all_ relevant information: the complete compile log, the complete declaration of `A` (or at least of all the constructors), and the function doing the `return` (and maybe also the context of the call to that function).

Answer (score 5):

You are missing copy constructor for `A` that will create copy of class created with `A("")`. Most likely actual copy will be eliminated with RVO, but you still need to provide copy constructor.

Comment: Note C++ will usually automatically define a copy constructor.  Since it isn't, that's probably because a base class or member doesn't have an accessible copy constructor.